# Can't resolve axios promise in redux reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I am trying to get channels list from slack api and store them in redux store and react.

axios is getting a [[PromiseValue]] which I can not get the objects in it:

reducer file:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/types";
import { getChannels } from "./../services/channelService";

const channelsReducer = (state = getChannels(), action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.GET_CHANNELS:
            return state;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

channelService.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getChannels = async () => {
    const token =
        "token";
    return await axios
        .get(`https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=${token}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        });
};
```

action.js file:

```
import * as actionTypes from "./types";

export const getChannels = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.GET_CHANNELS
    });
};
```

and my component file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "./../actions/channelsActions";

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {};
    componentDidMount() {}
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.channels);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        channels: state.channels
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Navbar);
```

How can I access objects inside this promise from axios?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `getChannels()` in your reducer because it is an async function and your reducer is synchronous. However, you can dispatch your action after your api response comes back

```
export const getChannels = (dispatch) => {
    const token = "token";
    axios
        .get(`https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=${token}`)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(//your action here... )
        });
};
```

Call this from within your component and pass in dispatch.

You could alternatively modify your existing action as suggested by Emile:

```
  export const getChannels = () => dispatch => {
     const token = "token";
     axios
        .get(`https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=${token}`)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                 type: actionTypes.GET_CHANNELS, 
                 payload: response.data
               })
        });
    };    
 };
```

Comment: I don't want to polute my component. Do I have to do that?

Comment: No, not if you're using redux. You can trigger the channel fetching wherever you like and dispatch an action to pop it in the store and then get it in your Component via `connect()`

Comment: I'm doing it right now. Re-check my component part in code

Comment: ah cool, well in that case you're free to trigger your api call wherever you like (but you'll need access to the store via dispatch, so somewhere inside your `<Provider>`

Comment: @Afshin The way to do it would be in your action, and I see that you're already using thunk-actions so it would be a matter of calling the `getChannels` function from your `channelService` file inside your `getChannels` action. So your action stays super simple, isolating the fetching logic to your service file like you already do right now.

Comment: Good shout, have added it as an option